# Android - Fragment inside a fragment - Preserve state

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I am trying to have tabs fragment inside a swipe view fragment (named BROWSE). When BROWSE is accessed, a connection to a remote server is done, data is retrieved and displayed in a gridview inside a tab, when a different tab is clicked, a new connection is made, and the gridview is populated with new data.

The problem is that I can’t save the state of the tabs, I don’t want to make a connection each time, only when the tabs are first clicked a connection to the database is made, if a tab is clicked again I want the gridview to preserve the state.

Here is the onCreate method of the BROWSE fragment, in this method, I am initializing a loader to get the data from the remote server:

```
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




            if (t == 0) {
            Log.v("BROWSE","++++++++ Inside onCreate t = 0 ++++++++");

            tweets = Collections.emptyList();
            // This is our REST action.

            Uri twitterSearchUri = new Uri.Builder()
            .scheme("http")
            .authority(ip)
            .path("browse.php")
            .appendQueryParameter("SpecialOffer", "0")
            .build();

                Bundle params = new Bundle();
            //    params.putString("q", "android");
                params.get("salim slem");
                // These are the loader arguments. They are stored in a Bundle because
                // LoaderManager will maintain the state of our Loaders for us and
                // reload the Loader if necessary. This is the whole reason why
                // we have even bothered to implement RESTLoader.
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putParcelable(ARGS_URI, twitterSearchUri);
                args.putParcelable(ARGS_PARAMS, params);


            //For loading Images    
            //--------------------------------------------------    

                options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_image)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_for_empty_url)
                .cacheInMemory()
                .cacheOnDisc()
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .build();


            //--------------------------------------------------    



                // Initialize the Loader.
                getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_TWITTER_SEARCH, args, this);

            }

            if(t == 1) {

                Log.v("BROWSE","++++++++ Inside onCreate  t = 1 ++++++++");

                tweets = Collections.emptyList();
                // This is our REST action.

                Uri twitterSearchUri = new Uri.Builder()
                .scheme("http")
                .authority(ip)
                .path("browse.php")
                .appendQueryParameter("SpecialOffer", "1")
                .build();

                    Bundle params = new Bundle();
                //    params.putString("q", "android");
                    params.get("salim slem");
                    // These are the loader arguments. They are stored in a Bundle because
                    // LoaderManager will maintain the state of our Loaders for us and
                    // reload the Loader if necessary. This is the whole reason why
                    // we have even bothered to implement RESTLoader.
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putParcelable(TAB1_ARGS_URI, twitterSearchUri);
                    args.putParcelable(TAB1_ARGS_PARAMS, params);


                //For loading Images    
                //--------------------------------------------------    

                    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_image)
                    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_for_empty_url)
                    .cacheInMemory()
                    .cacheOnDisc()
                    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                    .build();

                //--------------------------------------------------    

                    // Initialize the Loader.
                    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(TAB1_LOADER_TWITTER_SEARCH, args, this);
                }
        }
```

here is the onCreateView method where the tabs are created along with the gridview

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.v("BROWSE", "Inside OnCreateView");

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview, container, false);

        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridViewImage);

        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageTextAdapter(view.getContext(), LOADING));

        // When an item in the gridview is clicked
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                FragmentPosition = 2;
                Log.v("BROWSE: POSITION OF ITEM IN GRIDVIEW","## "+position+" ##");
                DialogFragment newFragment = new BrowseDialogFragment(position);
                newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "missiles");

            }
        });

        // creating tabs
        mTabHost = (TabHost) view.findViewById(R.id.testtabhost1); 
        mTabHost.setup();
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("TAB 1").setContent(R.id.gridViewImage)); 
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("TAB 2").setContent(R.id.gridViewImage)); 
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3").setIndicator("TAB 3").setContent(R.id.gridViewImage)); 
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0); 



        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {


            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

            int i = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
             Log.i("@@@@@@@@ ANN CLICK TAB NUMBER", "------" + i);

             if (i ==0) {
                 Bundle tempBundle = new Bundle();
                 t = 0;
                onCreate(tempBundle);
        }

             if (i ==1) {
                 Bundle tempBundle = new Bundle();     
                 t = 1;
                 onCreate(tempBundle);
                }

              }
            });

        return view;
    }
```

I guess my problem is that I can’t give “savedInstanceState” to onCreate from onCreateView. My question is, how can I save the state in the tabs? Maybe using the bundle given to onCreate, but I haven't found how to do it!

Thank you in advance for your help!!

That s the UI I’m talking about:

[image]

And that’s the UI when a tab is pressed again:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an database for that case. It's pritty easy to realize that:
[tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

So what you should do:

1. Get the remote data
2. Save it in the SQLite DB
3. Create a Methode which checks how old the data is in the db.
4. For Example if the data is older than 10minutes, it should take the remote data and update the Table.

I hope this helps.

Best Regards

safari

Answer (score 0):

The savedInstanceState variable is passed to the **onViewCreated** method, which is called immediately after **onCreateView**.

You should try to only inflate your layout and initialize your View fields in onCreateView (gridView, mTabHost, etc.), and restore the state (or set default state) in onViewCreated